# javascript verbose react redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, google-cloud-firestore

I have this:

```
await firebase
  .firestore()
  .collection("kategori")
  .get()
  .then(snapshot => {
    const data = snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({ [doc.id]: doc.data() }));
    dispatch({ type: "LOAD_KATEGORI", payload: data });
  });
```

which is mapping to the state

```
0: {something :{item1, item2, item3}}
1: {other_something :{item1, item2, item3}}
```

however I wanted it to map to the state

```
something: {item1, item2, item3}
other_something: {item1, item2, item3}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to make the result an object with the doc id as key and the doc data as value

```js
const data = snapshot.docs.reduce((res, doc) => ({ 
  ...res, 
  [doc.id]: doc.data()
}), {})
```

Also don't mix `await` and `.then` pick one and stick to it, personally i prefer `async/await` as it's easier to scan as it doesn't go into `.then` blocks

```js
const snapshot = await firebase.firestore().collection('kategori').get()

const data = snapshot.docs.reduce((res, doc) => ({ 
  ...res, 
  [doc.id]: doc.data()
}), {})

dispatch({ type: 'LOAD_KATEGORI', payload: data })
```

Answer (score 0):

Just reduce your data as you need, ex:

```
const payload = Object.keys(a).reduce((acc, curr) => {
    var k = Object.keys(a[curr])[0]
    acc[k] = a[curr][k]
    return acc
}, {})

dispatch({ type: 'LOAD_KATEGORI', payload })
```